# refresh/reload Datatable by button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

One more question of many more questions to come. I'm working with `Jquery` `Datatable` and now want to refresh/reload that table by simply clicking a bootstrap button below that table. Sound easy. I have to admit it must be easy but somehow I cannot find any help that works for me on here referring to this little issue. That's what I have so far:

[image]

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover droplist">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Filename</th>
                        <th>Size[bytes]</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Added</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        <?php 
                $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM file_upload ORDER BY id");
                  $result = $statement->execute();
                    $count = 1;
                    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                        echo '<tr name="'.$row['name'].'">';
                        echo "<td>".$count++."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['size']."</td>";
                        echo '<td><img src="'.$row['link'].'" alt="'.$row['name'].'" height="auto" width="100%"></td>';
                        echo "<td>".$row['type']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['date']))."</td>";
                        echo '<td><a class="delete" href="#" data-artname="'.$row['name'].'"><i class="fa fa-trash" ></i></a></td>';
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var table = $('.droplist').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
        // "scrollY":        "100px",
        // "scrollCollapse":  true,
            "paging":         true,
        //  "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        }

    });

    // Refresh datatable by clicking the refresh button (no auto refresh)

    $("#refreshbtn").on('click', function() {

    //          table.fnClearTable();
    //          table.fnDestroy();
    //          table.fnDraw();

    $("#refreshbtn").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>   updating ...');

    setTimeout(function (){
          $("#refreshbtn").html('<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>   Refresh ');
          }, 3000);
    });
```

It doesn't work for me with either `fnDestroy`, `fnDraw`, `fnClearTable` or `fnReloadAjax`. I've tried all of them. That really odd.

Comment: All those methods that you have written are obsolete. Read the new API documentation.

Comment: I see. Now detroy() and empty work for me to remove the table from DOM. Since I do not use AJAX I still don't know how to reload the data table. Any idea?